# Ruby syntax for passing block

Tags: ruby

Why syntax with curly braces works as expected:

```
class SomeClass
  include Parser::Http.new { |agent|
    # PASSED: This block was passed to Http::new
  }
end
```

While one with do...end passed to wrong target method?

```
class OtherClass
  include Parser::Http.new do |agent|
    # FAILED: This block was passed to Module::include
  end
end
```

How to make this both syntaxes work the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR** `do end` has lower precedence than `{ }`.

Actually, those syntaxes are not intended to work in the same way.

Here is a snippet from [the official docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/doc/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Block+Argument):

> The block argument sends a closure from the calling scope to the method.
>
> The block argument is always last when sending a message to a method. A block is sent to a method using `do ... end` or `{ ... }`:

```rb
my_method do
  # ...
end
```

> or:

```rb
my_method {
  # ...
}
```

> `do end` has lower precedence than `{ }` so:

```rb
method_1 method_2 {
  # ...
}
```

> Sends the block to `method_2` while:

```
method_1 method_2 do
  # ...
end
```

> Sends the block to `method_1`. Note that in the first case if parentheses are used the block is sent to `method_1`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

There is little to add to @Marian13's answer, except that you can circumvent the precedence problem when using bracketed blocks by wrapping the first method arguments with parenthesis.

```
class SomeClass
  include(Parser::Http.new) { |agent|
    # ...
  }
end
```

This is particularly useful when you want a one-liner to look good.