# Why is it wrong to replace curly brackets of block with "do..end" in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I am trying to use "reduce" to select the largest number in an array, and the specific logical judgment is written in a block. If I wrap the block in curly brackets, I get the expected result. If I wrap the block with "do..end", I get a TypeError (0 is not a symbol nor a string).

Here is the code:

```
p [5, 2, 9, 10, 7, 89, 70].reduce(0) { |acc, cv|
  if cv > acc   
    acc = cv    
  else
    acc                
  end
}
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of [Ruby Block Syntax Error](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/6854283/2988), [Code block passed to `each` works with brackets but not with `do`-`end` (ruby)](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/6718340/2988), [Block definition - difference between braces and `do`-`end` ?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/6179442/2988), [Ruby multiline block without `do` `end`](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/3680097/2988), [Using `do` block vs brackets `{}`](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/2122380/2988), [What is the difference or value of these block coding styles in Ruby?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/533008/2988), …

Comment: … [Ruby block and unparenthesized arguments](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/420147/2988), [Why aren't `do`/`end` and `{}` always equivalent?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/7487664/2988), [Wierd imperfection in Ruby blocks](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/7620804/2988), [Passing block into a method - Ruby](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/10909496/2988), [`instance_eval` block not supplied?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/12175788/2988), [block syntax difference causes “`LocalJumpError: no block given (yield)`”](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/18623447/2988), …

Comment: … [`instance_eval` does not work with `do`/`end` block, only with `{}`-blocks](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/21042867/2988), [`Proc` throws error when used with `do` `end`](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/25217274/2988), [Block not called in Ruby](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/29454056/2988), [Different behaviour of “`do … end`” and “`{ … }`” block in ruby](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/37638152/2988), [Ruby syntax for passing block](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61749537/2988), and [Difference between do..end and {} while using block](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68367908/2988).

Comment: Note that this can be expressed much simpler: `p [5, 2, 9, 10, 7, 89, 70].max`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Ruby parser does not understand your code if you don't supply
the parenthesis for the `p` method.

This version works:

```
p([5, 2, 9, 10, 7, 89, 70].reduce(0) do |acc, cv|
  if cv > acc   
    acc = cv    
  else
    acc                
  end
end)
```

Comment: Also worth noting that `acc = cv` is completely pointless as the return value of the block is passed along as `acc` on the next iteration. That whole condition can be expressed as `[acc, cv].max`.

Comment: Is there a theoretical reason why only parentheses can be used here?